# Date Range between the Last 2 Records Sql Server 2008

Tags: t-sql

Hi Given that I have a table with 2 columns.

Table Booking
Column Amount-TransactionDate

Get me total Amount between Last 2 transactionDate.

How do you do that ?How do you get the last transaction but 01
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common table expression (CTE) to assign a sequence number to each row based on descending order of the transaction date.  And then select the rows with a filter to get the last 2 rows.

This query displays the last two transactions in the table

```
WITH BookingCTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) as Sequence,
        Amount, TransactionDate
    FROM Booking
    )

SELECT Sequence, Amount, TransactionDate
FROM BookingCTE
WHERE Sequence <= 2
;
```

This query give you the total amount for the last two transactions.

```
WITH BookingCTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) as Sequence, Amount, TransactionDate
    FROM Booking
    )

SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM BookingCTE
WHERE Sequence <= 2
;
```

Comment: Hi, What you have done is more or less exactly what I need.
However I need to get o1 single record the Sum(Amount)

Thanks for your help